# Radiobutton in usage in btnClicked

Tags: c#, if-statement, radio-button

I made the following assignment to calculate contribution depending which sport you play. If I run the code I get a -180 as a result which I dont understand. Here's the code:

```
const double Football = 175;
const double Handball = 225;

private void btnCalculateFee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Age = int.Parse(AgeInput.Text);
    int Mem = int.Parse(MembershipInput.Text);

    double MemDiscF = Football - 20;
    double AgeDiscF = Football - 25;
    double MemAgeDiscF = Football - (MemDiscF + AgeDiscF);

    if (rbtnFootball.Checked == true && Age < 40 && Mem < 10)
    {
        lblFeePrint.Text = Football.ToString();
    }
    else if (rbtnFootball.Checked == true && Age < 40 && Mem > 10)
    {
        lblFeePrint.Text = MemDiscF.ToString();
    }
    else if (rbtnFootball.Checked == true && Age > 40 && Mem < 10)
    {
        lblFeePrint.Text = AgeDiscF.ToString();
    }
    else 
    {
        lblFeePrint.Text = MemAgeDiscF.ToString();
    }

    double MemDischM = Handball - 20;
    double AgeDiscM = Handball - 25;
    double MemAgeDiscM = Handball - (MemDischM + AgeDiscM);

    if (rbtnHandball.Checked == true && Age < 40 && Mem < 10)
    {
        lblFeePrint.Text = Handball.ToString("0.00");
    }
    else if (rbtnHandball.Checked == true && Age < 40 && Mem > 10)
    {
        lblFeePrint.Text = MemDischM.ToString("0,00");
    }
    else if (rbtnHandball.Checked == true && Age > 40 && Mem < 10)
    {
        lblFeePrint.Text = AgeDiscM.ToString("0,00");
    }
    else
    {
        lblFeePrint.Text = MemAgeDiscM.ToString("0,00");
    }
}
```

Comment: 225 - 405 = -180. It seems correct to me. Anyway, why don't you use the debugger to check the values of your variables while you step through code with F10?. Trust me, it is the best way to understand what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

Code is doing exactly what you told it to:
Handball = 225:

```
double MemDischM = Handball - 20;
        double AgeDiscM = Handball - 25;
        double MemAgeDiscM = Handball - (MemDischM + AgeDiscM);
```

MemDischM = 225- 20; = 205

AgeDiscM = 225- 25; = 200

MemAgeDiscM = 225- (205 + 200) = -180

Comment: I've figured it out! Stupid mistake it's late!